# Как подключиться через гит к чужому репозиторий и вносить изменения?

Tags: html, css, git, github

Я в git полный ноль. Мне дали задание(учебное), на гитхабе есть репозиторий с проектом. Нужно подключиться со своего компа к этому репозиторию и внести изменения в файлах верстки. Кто может подсказать как мне подключиться к этому репозиторию и работать с файлами? Файлы нужно скачать? Или как это вообще происходит? Очень нужно. И ещё файлы в формате php. А не обычный html. Как мне их открыть в редакторе?

Comment: Всё это должен рассказать в первую очередь владелец этого репозитория

Comment: «Как мне их открыть в редакторе?» — точно так же, как и обычный html

Comment: "задание(учебное)," -- "подключиться со своего компа к этому репозиторию и внести изменения в файлах верстки" --- точно учебное а не делаешь за дядю? учебные даются в отрыве от чего либо. Либо говорят создать свою репку. но никак не изменить существующий проект

Comment: Устанавливаешь себе на комп git. Затем если из консоли - пишешь `git clone ПУТЬ_К_РЕПОЗИТОРИЮ ПУТЬ_КУДА_СКАЧАТЬ` и правишь файлы в любом редакторе.

Comment: У гитхаба вверху над кодом есть зеленая кнопка Code, нажмите и там написано как склонировать репозиторий.  php можете редактирвоать любым редатором (Visual Studio Code, phpStorm, webStorm) а вот запустить файл php - нужно сервер Apach

Comment: Вм еще права должны дать чтоб потом назад на гит залить изменения или ветку с правами выделеть

Comment: Получается я клонирую репозиторий к себе. И вношу изменения. Но эти изменения сохраняются в моем клоне или в репозитории владельца?

Comment: почитайте https://medium.com/nuances-of-programming/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%81-git-%D0%B8-github-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-54ea2567d76c Можно начать с раздела "я вообще ничего не знаю" и "Подайте мне вот этот проект!"